# Metropolis Hastings Algorithm for an epidemic in R: Why is my code returning negative values of beta_store?

Tags: r, model, ode, montecarlo, mcmc

I am trying to sample the parameter "beta" for a transmission dynamic model for COVID-19 (solved using ode in R), using the Metropolis Hastings Algorithm. I have first defined a function cBeta(x,a,b) to calculate the likelihood further in the metropolis hastings function (defined in the code below). My code is generating negative values of beta_store, and I am not sure why. Can someone please help? Thank you in advance.

```
library(deSolve)   # package with functions to solve the model
library(reshape2)  # package with functions to turn the model output into a long format
library(ggplot2)   # package for plotting
library(plyr)      # for rbind


#Initial number of people in each compartment of the model

initialvalues1<-  c (U  = 1 - (10^-5), # people uninfected or susceptible to COVID-19
                     E1 = 10^-5,       # current number of people exposed
                     E2 = 0,           # no one is recovered at the beginning of the simulation
                     A1 = 0,
                     A2 = 0,
                     P1 = 0,
                     P2 = 0,
                     S1 = 0,
                     S2 = 0,
                     R1 = 0,
                     R2 = 0,
                     J  = 0,
                     N  = 1) 

parameters1 <- c(beta1 = 0.265,  # transmission rate from symptomatic infection #0.268
                 beta2 = 0,
                 eeta = 0.275,   # amongst those exposed, rate of developing infectiousness
                 psym = 0.495,   # proportion developing symptoms
                 k = 0.83,       # relative infectiousness of asymptomatic vs symptomatic infection
                 r = 1,          # amongst those with pre-symptomatic infection, rate of developing symptoms
                 gamma = 0.2,    # recovery rate 
                 #w = 0,         # per-capita rate at which post infection immunity wanes
                 m = 1,          # connectivity matrix?
                 mu = 0.0029)    # average morality rate for severe case


times1 <- seq(from = 1, to = 395, by = 1) 

# Original Model 

COVID_model_revised <- function(time, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(time,state,parameters)), 
       {
         
         N <- U + E1 + E2 + A1 + A2 + P1 + P2 + S1 + S2 + R1 + R2 
         
         lambda1 <-  m * (beta1* (S1 + (k* ( A1 + P1))))  
         
         lambda2 <-  m * (beta2* (S2 + (k* ( A2 + P2)))) 
         
         dU      <-  - (lambda1 + lambda2)*U
         
         dE1     <-  (lambda1*U)  - (eeta*E1)
         
         dE2     <-  (lambda2*U)  - (eeta*E2)
         
         dA1     <-  (eeta* (1-psym)*E1) - (gamma*A1)
         
         dA2     <-  (eeta*(1-psym)*E2)  - (gamma*A2)
         
         dP1     <-  (eeta*psym*E1) - (r*P1)
         
         dP2     <-  (eeta*psym*E2) - (r*P2)
         
         dS1     <-  (r*P1) -  ((gamma + mu)*S1)
         
         dS2     <-  (r*P2) -  ((gamma + mu)*S2)
         
         dR1     <-  ((A1 + S1)*gamma)
         
         dR2     <-  ((A2 + S2)*gamma)
         
         dJ      <-   (P1 + P2)*r
         
         dN      <-  - (S1 + S2)*mu
         
         return(list(c(dU, dE1, dE2, dA1, dA2, dP1, dP2, dS1,dS2, dR1, dR2, dJ,dN)))  # Return the number of people in each 
         # compartment at each timestep in the same
         # order as the input state variables.
       } )
}



output_covid_new<-as.data.frame(ode(y=initialvalues1,     # Solving the differential equations using 
                                    times = times1,          # the "ode" (Ordinary Differential Equations) algorithm.
                                    func = COVID_model_revised, 
                                    parms = parameters1))

# daily incidence

AI_new1 <- diff (output_covid_new[,13])  

AI_new1


output_covid_plot <- data.frame("time"=output_covid_new$time[1:394], "AI"= AI_new1)

plot(output_covid_plot$time,output_covid_plot$AI, xlab = "Days from introduction", ylab = "Daily Incidence per million of the population" )


# Metropolis Hastings

cBeta <- function(x,a,b)

{
  
  return ( ifelse(x < 0, value <- -Inf,  value <- lgamma(a + b) - lgamma(a) - lgamma(b) + 
                    
         ( (a-1)*lgamma(x) ) + ( (b-1)*lgamma(1-x) ) ) )
  
}

MH_first <- function (betasto0,t)     # t is the number of steps taken
  
{

  beta_store <- rep(0,t)
  betasto0   <- beta_store[1] 
  
  sp_store <- rep(0,t)
  
  
  for (i in 2:t)
  {
    
    beta_prop <- rnorm(1, mean = beta_store[i-1], sd = sqrt(0.01))

    parameters_MH <- c(beta1 = beta_prop,  # transmission rate from symptomatic infection #0.268
                       beta2 = 0,
                       eeta = 0.275,       # amongst those exposed, rate of developing infectiousness
                       psym = 0.495,      # proportion developing symptoms
                       k = 0.83,          # relative infectiousness of asymptomatic vs symptomatic infection
                       r = 1,             # amongst those with pre-symptomatic infection, rate of developing symptoms
                       gamma = 0.2,       # recovery rate
                       m = 1,             
                       mu = 0.0029)     # average morality rate for severe case

      times1 <- seq(from = 1, to = 395, by = 1)
      

      # To sovle the COVID-19 model using ode

      output_covid_MH <-as.data.frame(ode(y=initialvalues1,     
                                         times = times1,          
                                         func = COVID_model_revised,
                                         parms = parameters_MH))

      # date of the max. value of symptomatic infection (S1) => seroprevalence peak (R1)
      
      symp_peak <- which.max(output_covid_MH[,9]) 
      
      sp_prop <- (output_covid_MH[symp_peak,11])

      Y <- runif(1)
      
      r <- exp( cBeta(sp_prop,159,2116) - cBeta(sp_store[i-1],159,2116) )

     
     if (i == 2)
        
      { 
        sp_store[i] <- sp_prop
        
        beta_store[i] <- beta_prop
      
      }
      
      else 
        
      { 
  
        ifelse ( Y < r,  sp_store[i] <- sp_prop,  sp_store[i] <- sp_store[i - 1] )
        
        ifelse ( Y < r,  beta_store[i] <- beta_prop,  beta_store[i] <- beta_store[i - 1] )
        
      }
      
   
  }
  
  return(beta_store)
  
  }


# calling the function

model_plot <- MH_first(0.26,10000)
```

Comment: `ifelse()` is a vectorized function that returns a result, use it like `result <- ifelse(...)`. Doing `<-` assignment *inside* the `ifelse()` arguments is a Bad Idea and may not work they way you want it to. Use `if(){}else{}` for this.

Comment: I haven't run your code... it's quite a lot of code to ask for help with (can you do anything to isolate the problem a bit more and make your example **minimal**??). But I looked at how `beta_store` gets updated, and sometimes you assign `beta_prop` to `beta_store`. So I found the definition `beta_prop <- rnorm(1, mean = beta_store[i-1], sd = sqrt(0.01))`. A normal distribution can easily be negative--so it doesn't seem at all surprising that `beta_store` can be negative. Is there any reason it shouldn't be negative?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GregorThomas. Are you saying there should be two separate "if else" loops within the "else"? And yes, even though it's a normal distribution, the code is sampling using a metropolis algorithm, and should reject proposed values lesser than the previous stored ones. That check is also being incorporated with the "if (i == 2)" loop.

Comment: I tried running it with two separate "if else" loops within the "else" but that generates an error

Comment: I wouldn't call `if(){}` and `else{}` loops, and since your `Y < r` condition is the same, you don't need two. I would recommend a single `if(Y < r) { sp_store[i] <- sp_prop; beta_store[i] <- beta_prop } else { sp_store[i] <- sp_store[i - 1]; beta_store[i] <- beta_store[i - 1] }`.

Comment: Tried this as well, but I'm still getting negative values...

Comment: I see `if(i == 2) {... beta_store[i] <- beta_prop}` I don't see any check that `beta_prop` is positive, or greater than a previous value. Seems like when `i == 2` `beta_store[i]` is whatever normally distributed value is drawn for `beta_prop`.

Comment: And when `i != 2` you check `Y < r`, but `Y <- runif(1)` is just random, so it also doesn't seem to matter if `beta_prop` is negative or greater than any previous values.

Comment: Also forgot to add that to my previous comment that along with the negative value, all other values are 0.

Comment: The original two "ifelse (Y<r)" have to be performed in that order, so it's a bit tricky for the two to be merged into one, but I think that's where the problem is originating from...

Comment: Why would the order matter for those two consecutive `if(Y < r)`s? Nothing else is executed in between and they don't share any objects in common.

Comment: I think you need to use `browser()` or take this out of the function and execute it one line at a time. There's a great quote that all bugs are bad assumptions you're making about the code--you just need to find where you assume one thing is happening but the code is doing something else. If you're having problems as early as `i = 1` or `i = 2` it won't take long to find the problem. Just execute it one line at a time and check the results of every line.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas, I have tried that as well. I have just hit a dead end with this, so chose to post it here for suggestions

Comment: Your code isn't runnable as it is.  Please include the missing bits:  whatever package supplied `ode()`, `COVID_model_revised`, etc.

Comment: Some general advice:  First, make the changes @GregorThomas suggested (i.e. don't use `ifelse()`).  Second, avoid taking the exponential of the log likelihoods:  that may overflow or underflow.  Instead, take the log of `Y`.

Comment: @user2554330 have added the COVID_model_revised

Comment: @user2554330 I think asking for **more** code is the wrong way to go with this question. It would be great if OP could isolate the problem and share a lot **less code**.

Comment: @GregorThomas, code that runs is better than code that doesn't run.  Minimal code that runs would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

First, follow @GregorThomas's advice:  don't use `ifelse()`, change the decisions to something like this:

```
  if( Y < r) {
     sp_store[i] <- sp_prop
     beta_store[i] <- beta_prop
  } else {
     sp_store[i] <- sp_store[i - 1]
     beta_store[i] <- beta_store[i - 1]
  }
```

Your Metropolis ratio doesn't look at `beta`, it looks at `sp`.  You would reject any proposal that had a negative `sp`, but not a proposal that had a negative `beta`.  So that explains why you are seeing negative values.

I don't know anything about your model, so I can't tell you if it is implemented correctly.

Comment: Thanks, tried this. The first 4 values are positive, and others negative

Comment: Right, that's what your model says gives the higher likelihood.  I see it converge to near `beta = -4`. So this is a stats question, not a programming question anymore.

Comment: That's right, it goes up to -4 when I run it for t = 1,000.

Comment: If you're sure the model you're using can't have negative `beta`, then there's something wrong with the way you've implemented it. You should examine `COVID_model_revised` to see if it is doing what you think it should do.  I don't think anyone here on SO can help you with that, unless you make it a very specific question.